# Is it possible to use IF statement in WHERE clause and use INTO statement according to different IF values?

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, where-clause, opensql

is there any way to get these 2 SELECTs as one SELECT using something like IF in WHERE clause? And would using 1 select instead of 2 like this make 
any runtime difference? I'm using OpenSQL on SAP-ABAP. Providing code would be very helpful. TY.

EDIT: i just realised i wasn't very clear, i also want to get data INTO different parameters according to results of IF statement. For example if y = a then INTO lv_xa. if y = b then INTO lv_xb.

```
SELECT SINGLE x
FROM table
WHERE y = a
INTO lv_xa.

SELECT SINGLE x
FROM table
WHERE y = b
INTO lv_xb.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the longest run time comes from the database SQL query compared to ABAP execution, you may use one SELECT with a WHERE with all conditions, and get the lines into an internal table and you will take the line you wish via an ABAP [table expression](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abentable_expressions.htm) (below: `result[ y = a ]`).

```
DATA result TYPE SORTED TABLE OF table WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY y.

SELECT y x
  FROM table
  WHERE y IN (a,b)
  INTO TABLE result.

lv_xa = result[ y = a ]-x.
lv_xb = result[ y = b ]-x.
```

Note that a table expression may stop the execution of your program if the line is not found, so I let you read the documentation linked above to find out the better way to avoid it.

Comment: This seems like the closest one. I wasn't expecting to get it done just with a single select, but a man can hope right :) Ty for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need a simple CASE statement -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN y = a THEN x END, CASE WHEN y = b THEN x END
FROM table
WHERE y IN (a, b)
INTO lv_xa, lv_xb
```